# Unity smooth touch x coordinate

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a 2D mobile game and I need touch and drag objects. Here is a script (objects don't move smoothly with this script). I want moving objects at position where is a finger on the that time.

```
public float speed;

    void  Update ()
    {
        if (Input.touchCount > 0 && Input.GetTouch(0).phase == TouchPhase.Moved) 
        {

            Vector2 touchDeltaPosition = Input.GetTouch(0).deltaPosition;

            transform.Translate(touchDeltaPosition.x * speed, 0, 0);
        }
```

What to do?

Thanks 
Kind regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not user `speed` here as it would give you the exact position without any delay. So try to remove `speed` like `transform.Translate(touchDeltaPosition.x, 0, 0);`

**UPDATE:**

You can also use `Vector3.MoveTowards`. Give it a try

```
void  Update ()
    {
        if (Input.touchCount > 0 && Input.GetTouch (0).phase == TouchPhase.Moved) { //pomicanje trake po x-osi na touch screenu
            // pokret prsta od zadnjeg frejma
            Vector3 touchDeltaPosition = Input.GetTouch (0).deltaPosition;
            // Za x-os
            transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards (transform.position, new Vector3 (Mathf.Clamp (touchDeltaPosition.x, -2.5f, 2.5f), transform.position.y, transform.position.z), 1);
        }
    }
```

Instead of `transform.Translate`

It should work nicely.

Comment: Now, speed of my objects is very very fast. Dosen't follow my finger. Also, I limited moving my objects to ending limits.

Comment: Your objects Y and Z positions are already set to `0` or not?

Comment: Yes, and it's moving only on x axis, but speed is very high. I just move my finger for one milimeter and my object is on the end corner.

Comment: 5 errors: Assets/pomicanjeTrake.cs: error CS1502: The best overloaded method match for `UnityEngine.Vector3.Vector3(float, float, float)' has some invalid arguments.Assets/pomicanjeTrake.cs(17,136): error CS1503: Argument `#3' cannot convert `object' expression to type `float'.Assets/pomicanjeTrake.cs(17,54): error CS1502: The best overloaded method match for `UnityEngine.Vector3.MoveTowards(UnityEngine.Vector3, UnityEngine.Vector3, float)' has some invalid arguments.Assets/pomicanjeTrake.cs(17,54): error CS1503: Argument `#2' cannot convert `object' expression to type `UnityEngine.Vector3'

Comment: It should be transform.position.z in last, sorry for the typo

Comment: Work fine, but my object move at all screen, I only need x axis (left-right), I tried change instead 1 to 0, but then is everything fixed. My game is 2D

Comment: Are you sure you have assign `0` in `Y` like this `transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards (transform.position, new Vector3(touchDeltaPosition.x, 0, transform.position.z), 1);`

Comment: Yes, 100%. If you want, I can send you my script to your mail. So, when I tap my objects, It firstly move up, and then I swiping left-right, but always I can moving up-down

Comment: Sorry for late reply. I did edit my answer, your `Update` should be like that, no more checks is needed. If it still occurs then check other scripts as well if they are the cause of that.

Comment: It's ok. Thanks for your help. No, I have the same problem. Objects firstly move up...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99185/discussion-between-hamza-hasan-and-mavericks).

Comment: Check now. I did change the y position to its own